# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am working on an application that streams ResultSet over a network. I ended up using a CachedRowSetImpl class. But when I connect to an Oracle DB, I get an error like this

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Please help.

The source code is as follows:

```
ResultSet res = response.getResultSet(); //resultset from the server
while (res.next()) {
    Agent agent = new Agent();
    agent.setName(res.getString(2));
    agent.setMobile(res.getString(1));
    agent.setBalance(res.getLong(4));
    agent.setLastUpdate(res.getDate(3)); //date from the result set
    agent.setAccountNumber(res.getString(5));
}
```

The error ...

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
>       at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getDate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:2139)

Comment: post your code and stack trace

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getDate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:2139)

Comment: post your code also and entire stack trace

Comment: also edit it inside your question only rather than adding it in the comment

Comment: ResultSet res = response.getResultSet(); //resultset from the server
                while (res.next()) {
                    Agent agent = new Agent();
                    agent.setName(res.getString(2));
                    agent.setMobile(res.getString(1));
                    agent.setBalance(res.getLong(4));
                    agent.setLastUpdate(res.getDate(3)); //the date
                    agent.setAccountNumber(res.getString(5));

Comment: please edit your question with entire code and stack trace, not in the comment

Comment: what is the signature of `setLastUpdate` method ?

Comment: It is a getter method for a java.util.Date variable,lastUpdate.

Answer (score 37):

The javadoc for [ResultSet.getObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) mandates that the JDBC type should be mapped to a Java type as prescribed by the JDBC spec (TIMESTAMP -> java.sqlTimestmp):

> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java
>   object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object
>   type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for
>   built-in types specified in the JDBC specification.

As you have noticed, the Oracle driver is by default **not compliant with the standard** and uses `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` instead (which does not extend `java.sql.Timestamp`). The good news is that you can force JDBC compliance by setting the **oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant** system property to `true` during vm startup:

```
java -Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true YourApplication
```

or programmatically

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant", "true")
```

Once you do this, getResult() will return instances of `java.sql.Timestamp`, as expected.

For more details see the relevant section from the [Oracle JDBC Driver Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17657/datacc.htm#i1023778), which describes several ways of setting oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant.

Comment: Vincent's answer explains why the exception is raised, but this (Bogdan's) answer is the reason the original code is seeing an oracle.sql.Timestamp object instead of a java.sql.Timestamp object. If you know you always want the J2EE13Compliant property set, you can do it in code using `Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant", "true") ;`

Answer (score 6):

I found a way out.

```
 oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP ts = (oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP) res.getObject("last_update");
 agent.setLastUpdate(new Date(ts.dateValue().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this this line to the JVM setting. It will work.

```
-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because [`oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html) is not derived from `java.sql.TIMESTAMP`:

> ```
> java.lang.Object
>   -> oracle.sql.Datum
>      -> oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP
> ```

You can't cast the former into the later.

Instead use [`oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP.timestampValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#timestampValue__):

> ```
> public Timestamp timestampValue(Calendar cal) throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Calls `toTimestamp` to convert internal Oracle `Date` and Calendar to a Java `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using the timestampValue() function present in the oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP class. This method will convert oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP into java.sql.Timestamp.

oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP ts = (oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP) res.getObject("last_update");
 agent.setLastUpdate(ts.timestampValue());

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `setLastUpdate` is expecting an object of `java.sql.Date` type.

Now when you use `agent.setLastUpdate(res.getDate(3));`

The `res.getDate(3)` must be returning an object that your method doesn't expect so your there may be `ClassCastException` for that.

Try this code and see whether it solves your problem or not:

```
agent.setLastUpdate(new java.util.Date(res.getDate(3).getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you used `getTIMESTAMP()` instead of `getTimestamp()`. The methods `getTIMESTAMP()` (and `getDATE()` are extension in [`OracleResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleResultSet.html) which return Oracle specific types.

If not then you are not using a JDBC driver, because the returntype of `getDate()` is `java.sql.Date` and of `getTimestamp()` is `java.sql.Timestamp`, so it can't be a totally different type as in your question.