# oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I was trying to execute SELECT statement by connecting from Java to Oracle DB. One of the table has column with Timestamp datatype .when i ran the jUnit test i got the below exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getTimestamp(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.getTimestamp(ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.java:491)
at com.wellpoint.provider.rnr.biz.integration.dao.PropsDAO.buildPropsResponse(PropsDAO.java:1476)
at com.wellpoint.provider.rnr.biz.integration.dao.PropsDAO.populatProps(PropsDAO.java:1320)
at com.wellpoint.provider.rnr.biz.integration.dao.PropsDAO.getProps(PropsDAO.java:388)
at com.wellpoint.provider.rnr.biz.managers.PropsManager.getProps(PropsManager.java:95)
at com.wellpoint.provider.rnr.biz.managers.PropsTest.testGetProps(PropsTest.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
...... .....
```

set the **-D oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true** for PropsTest.java in the argument VM tab, tried to execute and got the below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/J2EE13Compliant=true
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

am i missing adding any jars or have to follow some other approach to solve this?

Any of your help is appeciated!

Thanks!

Comment: show the codes pleases

Comment: instead of casting, do new myResult.[timestampValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#timestampValue__)

Comment: Please edit your last comment into your question.

Comment: Thankyou all for your suggestions. I resolved the same by modifying the type of columns in code.

Comment: Relate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269564/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-timestamp-cannot-be-cast-to-java-sql-ti

Answer (score 4):

I've also seen this ClassNotFound exception. And it was caused by space between -D and o...

```
-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are missing the Oracle JDBC driver JAR in your runtime classpath.

Check out [Oracle JDBC driver downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.htm) page.