# Exception calling method timestampValue() on oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP from ColdFusion

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

This question it to some extend inspired by [Retrieving Data From Returned Oracle Timestamp Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850545/retrieving-data-from-returned-oracle-timestamp-column/66230641)

I query my Oracle database like

```
<cfquery name="getstuff" ...>
  SELECT timestampfld
  FROM myTable
</cfquery>
```

The column is of type timestamp and is returned as `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`.
A call to

```
<cfdump var="#timestampfld#">
```

displays that the class is supposed to have a function [timestampValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#timestampValue__) that takes no arguments. However, when I call

```
<cfdump var="#timestampfld.timestampValue()#">
```

I'm presented with an exception

> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and
> argument types or the timestampValue method is overloaded with
> argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion
> found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java
> object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast
> function to reduce ambiguity.

How can I call the method `timestampValue()` on my column?

**EDIT**

When I `CFDUMP` the `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` I see the followig picture which says there is a `timestampValue()` method.
[image: CFDUMP of oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP]

Also, when I look into the Oracle Thin driver JAR file using a Java Decompiler I see the signature of the method

[image: Java Decompiler]

Comment: AFAIK there is no `timestampValue()` method in either Oracle or CFML.  Whenever I want to get the value of the timestamp field from an Oracle select, I typically use the `to_char()` Oracle function.  For example `SELECT to_char(timestampfld, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM myTable`.

Answer (score 0):

As so many times in the ColdFusion world: Ben Nadel to the [rescue](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2984-the-coldfusion-10-invoke-function-works-with-most-java-objects.htm).

I already tried to call `timestampValue()` using the `CFINVOKE` tag like

```
<cfinvoke component="#timestampfld#" method="timestampValue" returnvariable="ts"></cfinvoke>
```

but was presented with an exception

> The **component** attribute can either be a string (component name) or a component object
>
> The **component** attribute in **cfinvoke** tag has invalid value.

Said blog describes how to use the function instead of the tag:

> fortunately, invoke() works with any non-String Java object where the invoke() signature is disambiguated

This made me write the following code, which actually outputs a nicely formatted date

```
#dateTimeFormat( invoke( timestampfld, "timestampValue" ), "dd.mm.yyyy HH:nn:ss.L" )#
```