# Oracle TIMESTAMP and Mybatis issue

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, mybatis

I'm using mybatis in my web application.

I'm executing the below select query:

```
<select id="retrieveSearchResultReferrals" resultType="hashmap" parameterType="map">
    select *
    from 
        table(xxxx.test_abc_pk.retrieveDA(#{searchString}))
</select>
```

Of the columns in result some are DATE data type and one column is TIMESTAMP data type.

Mybatis is converting DATE column correctly to java.sql.Date BUT for the TIMESTAMP column it is converting it to oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP instead of java.sql.Timestamp.

Any ideas on how can I make mybatis to convert TIMESTAMP to java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: how about jdbcType="TIMESTAMP",  i read it somewhere long ago.! Ofcourse you have to set property for individual column.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" can be used if I'm using resultMap and my custom Java object but here I'm using mybatis hashmap as resultType. I'm not sure how can I do a custom mapping in this case.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting property `oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true` for your application.

See [java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269564/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-timestamp-cannot-be-cast-to-java-sql-ti/13270380)