# oracle.sql.timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.date when trying to convert timestamp field

Tags: java, datetime, type-conversion, timestamp, jdbctemplate

I have `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` field in my database table which is timestamp datatype.
I am using plane `jdbcTemplate` for database execute queries.

Below is part of my code which is working fine. But I see an issue on the line

```
latestModDate = rowSet.getString("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");
```

Because I am trying to treat `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` timestamp datatype field as a string it might create problem in my code in future.

I tried to update the line below and then declare `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` as `timestamp` datatype but getting error as `oracle.sql.timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.date`.

```
latestModDate = rowSet.getTimestamp("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");
```

I really dont know how to treat `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` as timestamp. I really dont want to make change in system property like below as i want to handle this issue in code:

```
java -Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true YourApplication
or
System.getProperties().setProperty("oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant", "true")
```

Below is part of my code:

```
            String orderID = null, extOrdId = null, latestModDate = null;                

            while (rowSet.next()) {
                latestModDate = rowSet.getString("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare `latestModDate` of type [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).
2. Get [java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from `latestModDate` as follows:

   ```
   Instant instant = latestModDate.toInstant();
   ```

Once you have the object of `Instant`, you can convert it to any other modern date-time object as per your requirement e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2020-06-27T08:55:12.317754Z
2020-06-27T09:55:12.317754+01:00[Europe/London]
2020-06-27T09:55:12.317754+01:00
2020-06-27T09:55:12.317754
```

Some additional notes:

3. Do not use outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API. Use the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).
4. `LocalDateTime` drops off information like Zone Offset and Zone ID which may be required in your business logic. Therefore, choose the appropriate class as per the table shown below ([Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html)):
   [image]

**[Update]**

The changes that you need to make in your code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp latestModDate;

if (rowSet.next()) {
    latestModDate = ((oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP) rowSet.getObject("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE")).timestampValue();
}

// If the record exist, update accordingly, else insert a new one.
if (latestModDate != null) {
    String sqlUpdate = "update " + tableName + " set LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE = sysdate, SOURCES = '" + fileName + "' where (ORDERID = '" + orderID + "' and EXTORDID = '" + extOrdId + "') or (ORDERID = '" + orderID + "' and EXTORDID is null)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdate);
    //...
```

**Note:** The function [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP#timestampValue](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#timestampValue__) returns a value in `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: sorry i am bit confused with the changes i have to do actually ...will be really helpful if you can please mentioned the changes i need to do thanks...specially this part i dont understand: Once you have the object of Instant, you can convert it to any other modern date-time object as per your requirement e.g.

Comment: @Symonds - I've added an update in my answer. I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: but are we still using rowSet.getString in your changes ?

Comment: sorry still geting same error oracle.sql.timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.date

Comment: @Symonds - Please post the error as a comment below this comment.

Comment: its on line latestModDate = rowSet.getTimestamp("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");
the error is :  java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @Symonds - I've updated the code accordingly. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: its still throws same error but as per your given link i tries few changes and its working now but i have small isse in checking isEmpty()...please see last part of my edited question

Comment: @Symonds - Remove `isEmpty()`. There is a function with this name in the class, `String` but not in `java.sql.Timestamp` class. I haven't used it in my code.

Comment: sorry one question if i remove isEmpty() does it make really difference ? because i really want to check this condition otherwise empty rows will get inserted ?

Comment: @Symonds - The check, `latestModDate != null` will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `latestModDate` as a `String` but as you've said it's a timestamp in the database, if you change the type to something like `java.util.Date` and then use `ResultSet.getDate()` this *should* fix your problem:

```java
Date latestModDate = rowSet.getDate("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");
```

Comment: i have changed the latestModDate type to java.util.Date latestModDate and then did the change you mentioned but still getting same error oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @Symonds this is a problem with the Oracle JDBC driver. Have a look at the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269564/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-timestamp-cannot-be-cast-to-java-sql-ti

Comment: If i do like this then its working now:             oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP latestModDate = null;
                latestModDate = (TIMESTAMP) rowSet.getObject("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");

Comment: so declaration normally  should not be java.util.Date but oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Symonds yes as per the discussion on that thread that is one solution. Adding a setting to the jvm means you could use my solution. (tbh I didn't realise this was a problem, I've always done it this way, someone must have added those settings to our project when it was first started 15 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`. Use `java.time.LocalDateTime`. `java.util.Date` is a hack and `java.sql.Date` is a hack on top of a hack.

```
LocalDateTime latestModDate;

while (rowSet.next()) {
    latestModDate = rowSet.getObject("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE", LocalDateTime.class);
}
```

Comment: i am using java 8 and i am getting the exception with the changes: org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: Not supported yet.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Not supported yet.

Comment: As per @Symonds comment `ResultSet` doesn't support `java.time.*` classes.

Comment: If i do like this then its working now: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP latestModDate = null; latestModDate = (TIMESTAMP) rowSet.getObject("LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE");